# PRISM - Reuse of Views With Child Regions - Can It Be Done?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I'm a bit of a PRISM newbie, but I've read the help documentation and can't seem to find out how to achieve the following (this is a WPF application)

I have a `Shell` (Window) that has 2 regions called 'region1' and 'region2'.
in the `Initialize` method of my one and only module, I am registering the same view with each region:

```
regionViewRegistry.RegisterViewWithRegion("Region1", typeof(View1));
regionViewRegistry.RegisterViewWithRegion("Region2", typeof(View1));
```

and when I run it everything is OK at this point as it creates 2 individual instances of `View1`, and places one in each region.

Now in `View1` I have declared its own region for injecting small child views

```
<ItemsControl Name="MainRegion" cal:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion" />
```

Now when I run my very simple PRISM app I get the following exception message:

> "Region with the given name is already
>   registered: MainRegion"

which suggests that I cannot have multiple instances of the same view if that view declares its own regions.

Is this correct ?

seems like a huge limitation.

I want my application to be highly modular, and to have view compose themselves of oother views (via regions) etc.

Or have I mis-read the documentation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a separation of shell-level regions with regions created by module views by using RegionScope.  Any region you create without a scope is "global" and having two regions with the same name in the same scope isn't supported.

You can read more about Region Scopes in this MSDN article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785479.aspx#id0090126

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9227557/921321), to see how child views can get the locally scoped `RegionManager` (very useful when opening other views from these scoped children)

Comment: Can any one please add a working link because the above link seems broken. :(

Comment: @HimeshSameera I assume this is what the link used to point to: http://web.archive.org/web/20150118003742/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785479.aspx#id0090126