# Child views do not instantiate their 'View-Models' automatically

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, view, prism

I have a WPF application in PRISM architecture.

I have a user-control (view) that has 2 user-controls inside it.

[Here is the idea :](http://s18.postimage.org/5i0vik8vr/SO_Question_6.png)
[image: Here is an idea :]

The reason why the 'Search user-control' is in its own user-control, is because I plan on reusing it in my application.

The main user-control (**black**) is called 'MainView' and has 2 user-controls in it:
- A user-control that has several textbox control I can filter by, and a 'Search' button
- A user-control that has a grid where I display the results

Each of these user-controls (and the parent, "Main View") are 'Views' and have 'View-Models'.

Everything is shown fine, except for the fact that the 'child' user-controls do not create their own 'View-Models' automatically.

In the view-model's classes I have the **'Export'** attribute,
and in the View's code-behind I have this snippet:

```
[Import]
FilterFieldsViewModel ViewModel
{           
    set
    {
       this.DataContext = value;
    }
}
```

Setting the 'View-Model' **does** happen for the 'Main View', but not for the child views...

I have a command binded to the 'Search' button of the 'Search User-control',
and when the application loads - I get an error in the output window, saying :

> BindingExpression path error: 'SearchCommand' property not found on 'object' ''MainWindowViewModel' (HashCode=22047425)'. BindingExpression:Path=SearchCommand; DataItem='MainWindowViewModel' (HashCode=22047425); target element is 'Button' (Name='Search'); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

For some reason the command from the 'child' user-control tries to bind to the view-model in the main window's view model, because for some reason - the child user-control's view model is not instantiated.

Why is this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dependency injection container (MEF) is not registering imports on the sub-views, because they are created by the `MainView` and not by MEF. What you probably want to do is create a property on your `MainViewModel`:

```
[Import]
public FilterFieldsViewModel FilterFieldsViewModel {get; set; }
```

Then in XAML:

```
<UserControl ....>
   ...
   <SearchUserControl DataContext="{Binding FilterFieldsViewModel}" ... />
   ...
</UserControl>
```

This enables MEF to create an instance of `FilterFieldsViewModel` for you and sends it down to the `SearchUserControl`.

This is the basic concept of course, maybe you would want to create a '`SearchViewModelBase`' or something that has the `FilterFieldsViewModel`.

Comment: Great solution, only one problem - doesn't this couple the main view with the child views ?

Comment: I read somewhere that a possible solution might be to define a region for the 'search control' and a region for the 'grid control', and then to use MEF to auto-load the controls to these regions. The problem with this approach is that during design - I won't be able to see what the final 'main' window will look like with the controls in it... you understand ?

Comment: @JohnMiner you are indeed correct, defining subregions is a better solution from an architectural point of view, but it is more work so I guess this is more of a 'financial' decision.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818840/prism-reuse-of-views-with-child-regions-can-it-be-done this question should provide some info on scoped child regions.