# Show the same module more than once

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I have Wpf Prism application and modules. I want to create lots of windows which have been populated by the same module. But i am taking this error :

> An exception occurred while creating a region with name 'PriceWindowRegion'. The exception was: System.ArgumentException: Region with the given name is already registered

How can i solve this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4822006/181771

Comment: You should add at least the code where the error occurs.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a scoped region in your windows as they all share the same `IRegionManager`. Additionally, make sure your user controls have their `PartCreationPolicy` attribute set to `NonShared`.

MSDN gives documentation on how to create multiple instances of the same region
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921098%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec42

> Scoped regions are available only with view injection. You should use
>   them if you need a view to have its own instance of a region. Views
>   that define regions with attached properties automatically inherit
>   their parent's RegionManager. Usually, this is the global
>   RegionManager that is registered in the shell window. If the
>   application creates more than one instance of that view, each instance
>   would attempt to register its region with the parent RegionManager.
>   RegionManager allows only uniquely named regions; therefore, the
>   second registration would produce an error.

[image: Scoped Regions]

```
IRegion detailsRegion = this.regionManager.Regions["DetailsRegion"];
View view = new View();
bool createRegionManagerScope = true;
IRegionManager detailsRegionManager = detailsRegion.Add(view, null, 
                            createRegionManagerScope);
```

> The Add method will return the new RegionManager that the view can
>   retain [sic] for further access to the local scope.